# Finding associations based on a logical AND instead of a logical OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

In my data model, a photo can have many tags associated with it.

So I have my `photos` table with two photos.

```
 id | file_name
----+----------------------
  1 | DSCN0317.jpg
  2 | DSCN0291.jpg
```

And I have my `tags` table with two tags

```
 id |      name
----+----------------
  5 | Vacation
  6 | Work
```

And I have a mapping table that ties two together.

```
   photo_id | tag_id
----------+--------
        1 |      5
        2 |      5
        2 |      6
```

So in this example, photo 1 has a single tag (5) and photo 2 has multiple tags (5, 6)

In my app, I need to find all photos with a certain list of tags. More importantly, I need to do it in a single query if at all possible

(the reasoning for why it needs to be a single query is outside the scope of this question, and has to do with the specific implementation of my app).

For example, I want to "find all photos that have both tags 5 and 6"

```
SELECT DISTINCT "photos".*
FROM "photos"
INNER JOIN "photo_tags"
  ON "photo_tags"."photo_id" = "photos"."id"
WHERE "photo_tags"."tag_id" IN (5, 6)
;
```

But this query is incorrect, because it returns all photos that have tags 6 *OR* 7. I'm looking for photos that have 6 *AND* 7.

Is there any way I can transform the above query to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the tags into arrays before joining. Then check if the required tags are contained by the array:

```
select distinct photos.*
from
    photos
    inner join (
        select photo_id as id, array_agg(tag_id) as tags
        from photo_tags
        group by photo_id
    ) photo_tags using(id)
where array[5, 6] <@ tags
```

Comment: Didn't even know you could do that! Thanks, marking yours as accepted because I tried running an `EXPLAIN` and `\timing` on each of the queries presented here and this was the fastest. Disclaimer for others: I only tried this with < 100 rows, and this query was within 10 ms of GurV's first query

Answer (score 1):

Try this using aggregation and condition distinct count on the tag_id:

```
select p.*
from photos p
join (
    select 
        photo_id
    from tags
    where 
        tag_id in (5, 6)
    group by 
        photo_id
    having 
        count(distinct tag_id) = 2
) t on p.id = t.photo_id;
```

Or a correlated query:

```
select p.*
from photos p
where exists (
    select
        1
    from tags t
    where
        t.tag_id in (5, 6)
        and t.photo_id = p.id
    group by 
        id
    having 
        count(distinct tag_id) = 2
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this just returns `p.id` since that's what it's grouping by, so I'd still need another query to grab the full photo records

Comment: @user2490003 - Updated my answer with optimization. Should be fast enough if you have proper indexes on photo_id and tag_id columns in tags table. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`, to find photos, that have both ID 5 and ID 6:

```
SELECT "photos".*
FROM "photos"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT "photo_tags"."tag_id" 
    FROM "photo_tags" 
    WHERE "photo_tags"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" 
        AND "photo_tags"."tag_id" = 5)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT "photo_tags"."tag_id" 
    FROM "photo_tags" 
    WHERE "photo_tags"."photo_id" = "photos"."id" 
        AND "photo_tags"."tag_id" = 6)
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how efficient this would be on large tables of photos, like 100k records or greater? I'd still be only querying by 2-3 tags at most, but just wondering if running an `EXISTS` subclause multiple times has any impact on larger photo tables.

Comment: @user2490003 Performance depends on many factors. If you have correct indexes (most likely on columns `photo_id` and `tag_id`) the performance should be reasonable, however that depends on actual data, your queries, specifics of the data, your required response time and many other factors. I suggest you test the performance on your data and see if that is acceptable for you or not.